# A process's files, the relation between files in mm_struct and files_struct?

Tags: c, linux, kernel

In `task_struct`, we can find there are:

```
struct mm_struct *mm, *active_mm;
struct files_struct *files;
```

`files_struct` contains pointers to up to 256 file data structures, each one describing a file being used by this process.

```
struct file * fd_array[NR_OPEN_DEFAULT];
```

`mm_struct` contains a `vm_area_struct`.

```
struct vm_area_struct * mmap;           /* list of VMAs */
```

And in `vm_area_struct`, we can find:

```
struct file * vm_file;          /* File we map to (can be NULL). */
```

So my question are:

1. what is the relationship between the files in `fd_array` and the `vm_file`?
2. Are all the files shown up in the `fd_array` will also be mapped in the `vm_area_struct` in a way similar as shown in the picture? Or, are all the files mapped in the `vm_area_struct` will show up in the `fd_array`?

Thanks,

[image: a busy cat]
<sub>(source: [duartes.org](http://static.duartes.org/img/blogPosts/memoryDescriptorAndMemoryAreas.png))</sub>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The files in `fd_array` are those that currently have a file descriptor associated with them (eg. opened with `open()`, `socket()` or similar), and those linked by VMAs are those that are mapped into process memory (eg. with `mmap()`).  Files can be in either category or in both,  so those files in `fd_array` are not necessarily linked by a VMA and vice-versa.